# Get all tag nodes inside another tag recursively

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html document consists of a `<div id = "main">`. Inside this `div` may be several levels of nodes, without a precise structure because is the user who creates the document content.
I wanto use a **JavaScript** function that returns all nodes within `div id = "main"`. Any tag is, taking into account that there may be different levels of children.

For now I have this function that returns all tags, even those outside to `div id = "main"`:

```
function getNodes() {
    var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (var elem = 0; elem < all.length; elem++) {
        //do something..
    }
}
```

As such this document:

```
<div id="main">

    <h1>bla bla</h1>

    <p>
        <b>text text text </b> text text <i>text</i>.
        <img src=".."></img>
    </p>

    <div>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
    </div>

    <p>..</p>

</div>
```

The function getNodes would return an array of object nodes (I don't know how to represent it, so I list them):

```
[h1, p, b, i, img, div, p, p, p]
```

Thank you

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for as the return value of getNodes.  Could you provide a sample of expected output?

Comment: Of sure! I edited the main message..

Comment: @MrLister I mistyped. Now I change, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). It returns a NodeList, not an array, but you can loop over it in the same way:

```
function getNodes() {
    var all = document.querySelectorAll("#main *");
    for (var elem = 0; elem < all.length; elem++) {
        //do something..
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/suuja4L5/

Comment: Thanks! It's perfect :)

Comment: and even if I wanted to return the leaf nodes? as for example the #text node or <br>..

Comment: Not clear what you mean; it should possibly be a second question. But you could test `all[elem].children.length` to see if a node has children or not.

Comment: I did the test on a node `<p>fruits</ p>` and says that `<p>` is a leaf node, yet has the child node `#text`. I would also need the nodes `#text`.

Comment: Sounds like you should submit this as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Just get the parent element and then get the descendents just as you did:

```
var mainDiv = document.getElementById("main");
mainDiv.getElementsByTagName("*")
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want all child of `<div id="main">`,then use the following :

`var children = document.querySelector("#main").children;`

Comment: That won't return all descendants, just the immediate children.